# First and Last function in sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, analytics

I want to get the first and last by date of each group.
I couldn't find documentation for it..

Basically the table is as:

```
select start, --timestamp
       first(open) partition by start order by asc, 
       max(high), 
       min(low), 
       last(close) partition by start order by asc
from candles_USDT_BTC
group by round(start/1800); --group by 15 min
```

Of course the first and last function does not exists, just for you guys to get the idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use additional `join`s:

```
select cub.s, cub.max_high, cub.min_low, f.open, l.close
from (select round(start/1800) as s, max(high) as max_high, min(low) as min_low,
             min(start) as first_start,
             max(start) as last_start
      from candles_USDT_BTC
      group by round(start/1800)
     ) cub join
     candles_USDT_BTC f
     on f.start = cub.first_start join
     candles_USDT_BTC l
     on l.start = cub.last_start;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use correlated subqueries to look up the row with the smallest/largest value in the group:

```
SELECT start,
       (SELECT open
        FROM candles_USDT_BTC AS c2
        WHERE round(c2.start / 1800) = round(candles_USDT_BTC.start / 1800)
        ORDER BY start ASC
        LIMIT 1),
       max(high),
       min(low),
       (SELECT close
        FROM candles_USDT_BTC AS c2
        WHERE round(c2.start / 1800) = round(candles_USDT_BTC.start / 1800)
        ORDER BY start DESC
        LIMIT 1)
FROM candles_USDT_BTC
GROUP BY round(start / 1800);
```